# Using handlebarJs with Angular

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

I was reading about Handlebar.Js and to me it tries to imitate what Angular.Js does. My question is whether handlebarJS is mainly for frameworks which are using expressions poorly or we might need to get help from HandlebarJS inside application on Angular framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Handlebars does somethings that AngularJS already provides out of the box: templating (e.g. taking a string like "here is {{myvalue}}!" and replacing the right places with the rights values). Handlebars is generally used alone, or together with "light" frameworks that don't include templating by default (Backbone for example).